# Unable to import class

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror, valueerror

```
Unit_Test/
    __init__.py
widgets/
    __init__.py
```

In `Unit_Test/__init__.py`:

```
from .. widgets import PathPicker
```

I get the following error: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`

`widgets/__init__.py` has a class named `PathPicker`.

**Edit:** In regards to the comment below, I am running the script from pyCharm. I opened the project from the folder 'lib' in this directory: `lib\pt_hil\utilities\PT_HIL_Interface_Utils\widgets`

Comment: @ctj232 Yeah that does not work either. Same error

Comment: How are you running your `Unit_Test.__init__` module? If you're giving the file name on the command line, I'm not surprised that it doesn't work (since that imports it as `__main__` rather than its normal package name).

Comment: Suggest you read question [**_Relative imports for the billionth time_**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time).

Comment: @Blckknght check the edit